# Unable to read file I have read permissions on

Tags: permissions, nfs

I have a group of files that I cannot access via `cat` or `vim` although I have read access.

The parent directory has permissions set as follows:

`drwxrws--- 2 test test_grp 94424 May 10 20:01 my_test_grp`

Then the file that I would like to access has permissions set as follows:

`-rwxrwx--- 1 test test_grp      3398 May 10 19:40 my_test_file.txt`

When I execute `id -gn`, it returns the following: `test_grp`

When I try to execute `cat`, I receive the following:

`cat: my_test_file.txt: Permission denied`

I've tried logging out and logging back in to the terminal, to no avail. Are there any other recommended steps to remediate this issue?

Also, I do not have `sudo` access.

**Update**
After doing a `df -h` I can see that the directory is in a location whose filesystem is a mounted NFS. Could that be a factor as well?

Comment: 94424 is a weird size for a directory.

Comment: @ilkkachu SELinux is disabled, `ls -Z` on the file lists as follows:
`-rwxrwx--- test test_grp ?                                my_test_file.txt`

Comment: Do you belong to the test_grp?

Comment: try `newgrp test_grp` and then try to acess the file

Comment: @Secko Yes, I'm a part of test_grp

Comment: @RomeoNinov Tried per your suggestion, but still getting permission denied.

Comment: @tomas I have a couple other folders that it's happening with. Their sizes are much smaller

Comment: @Glenak1911 How many groups are you a member of?  `AUTH_SYS` authentication only supports a maximum of 16 groups.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm currently a member of 2 groups, the `test_grp` and a `devs` group

Comment: @Glenak1911 OK, so that's not it. What are the mount options for this filesystem?  What OS is your NFS server running?

Comment: Did you log out and back in after joining the group?

Comment: @tomas I did log out and log back in, to be more accurate, started a new putty session and close my old one.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The mount options are `(ro,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=XX.XX.XX.XX,mountvers=3,mountport=300,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=XX.XX.XX.XX)` I do not have access to check the NFS Server OS. The OS of the host I've connected to is RHEL7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible explanation is that there are permissions on the server which NFS is unable to express. The permissions transmitted over the network are not what determines whether an access is authorized: the server gets to decide. Normally the permissions and the access control decision are based on the same information, and therefore they're consistent. However, if something along the way loses some information about permissions, then the two may be inconsistent.

Some examples of permissions that NFS is unable to express are access control lists (you're using NFSv3 which doesn't always support ACL; and NFSv4 has ACL but they aren't exactly the same as Linux's), and Linux security frameworks such as SELinux and AppArmor.

If this is the problem, then diagnosing it without access to the server would require a lot of guesswork. Without help from the server administrator, you're unlikely to resolve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I do believe this was the case, as it was reported to the administrator who manages the environment, and they were able to resolve the issue. I wasn't able to get details at the moment, but I believe this is the most correct answer in this situation.

Comment: @Glenak1911, Any idea of how they resolve? I am trying to access an usb drive attached in the router from RaspberryPi. Facing the same issue. I can read write from windows machines but not even read from mounted RPi location. permissions says -rwxrwxrwx

Comment: @JoyGeorgeKunjikkuru This thread was about NFS (and other network filesystems). It won't help you with a problem with a USB drive. Chances are that the problem is the way you're mounting it, but this can't be diagnosed in a comment. Ask a question where you explain your setup in detail.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' for quick response. I got it fixed. It was my mistake. When I checked permission it was showing proper so I did't check the case of path. But actually it was not 'media' intead 'Media'. cp failed but ls worked. One more lesson with linux casing. pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -lp /media/router/media/2020/2020-08-26-Giant-stairs/DJI_0159.MP4

-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi root 556408823 Aug 26 14:35 /media/router/media/2020/2020-08-26-Giant-stairs/DJI_0159.MP4

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cp /media/router/media/2020/2020-08-26-Giant-stairs/DJI_0159.MP4  /media/usbadata64gb/share